# Is there a way to change the google storage signed url to not include the name of the file?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a method that gets a signed url for a blob in a google bucket and then returns that to users. Ideally, I could change the name of the file shown as well. Is this possible?

An example is:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<path to file.mp4>?Expires=1580050133&GoogleAccessId=<access-id>&Signature=<signature>
```

The part that I'd like to set myself is `<path to file.mp4>`.

Comment: Do you mean that the object has a different name than the one you want to show in the url ? Or set a different name after the download ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "set a different name after the download". I do mean the first one though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is having something in the middle that will be responsible for the name "swap".

For example Google App Engine with an http trigger or Cloud Function with storage trigger that whenever you need it will fetch the object, rename it, and either provide it to the user directly or store it with the new name in another bucket.

Keep in mind that things you want to store temporarily in GAE or Cloud Functions need to be stored in "/tmp" directory.

Then for renaming, if you are using GAE possibly you can use something like:

import os
os.system([YOUR_SHELL_COMMAND])

However, the easiest but more costly approach is to set a Function with storage trigger that whenever an object is uploaded it will store a copy of it with the desired new name in a different bucket that you will use for the users.

Answer (score 0):

Use **response_disposition** like my python example here:

```
def generate_blob_signed_url(blob_name: str, download_as_name: str = None):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(os.getenv("BUCKET_NAME"))
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

    response_disposition = (
        f'attachment; filename="{download_as_name}"' if download_as_name else None
    )

    return blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
        method="GET",
        response_disposition=response_disposition,
    )
```

this will make the url be like:
[https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucketname}/{blob_name}](https://storage.googleapis.com/%7Bbucketname%7D/%7Bblob_name%7D)

But the file name in your download folder be **download_as_name**